# Qt Designer using Python 3.5 instead of Python 3.7

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

I'm using custom widgets for Qt Designer written on python 3 through PyQt5, and I had to use a resource file which needed a newer sip API, but in order to do that I had to update my python.

I'm on ubuntu 16.04 LTS, so I just downloaded python from python.org, and that's it, everything went through without problems, I manage to install python 3.7 without problems, if I use the "python3" command in bash the python 3.7 enviroment runs fine.

But when I Execute the Qt Designer I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ron/Qt/5.11.0/gcc_64/plugins/designer/python/QRoundProgressBarplugin.py", line 3, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyQt5/QtGui.so: undefined symbol: PySlice_AdjustIndices
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ron/Qt/5.11.0/gcc_64/plugins/designer/python/analogclockplugin.py", line 26, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyQt5/QtGui.so: undefined symbol: PySlice_AdjustIndices
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ron/Qt/5.11.0/gcc_64/plugins/designer/python/counterplugin.py", line 3, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyQt5/QtGui.so: undefined symbol: PySlice_AdjustIndices
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ron/Qt/5.11.0/gcc_64/plugins/designer/python/ledplugin.py", line 3, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyQt5/QtGui.so: undefined symbol: PySlice_AdjustIndices
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ron/Qt/5.11.0/gcc_64/plugins/designer/python/manometerplugin.py", line 3, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyQt5/QtGui.so: undefined symbol: PySlice_AdjustIndices
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ron/Qt/5.11.0/gcc_64/plugins/designer/python/switchplugin.py", line 3, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyQt5/QtGui.so: undefined symbol: PySlice_AdjustIndices
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ron/Qt/5.11.0/gcc_64/plugins/designer/python/thermometerplugin.py", line 3, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyQt5/QtGui.so: undefined symbol: PySlice_AdjustIndices
```

Of course, as you can see, the Qt Designer is using the lib from python 3.5 so is not able to find the symbol PySlice_AdjustIndices which is present on the newest PyQt5 (5.11), but on /usr/local/lib I have both python3.5 and python3.7 folders, each one with a PyQt5 version, but I don't really know how Qt Designer point to that folder instead of the python3.7 folder, any idea how?

And, just to let it know, is obvious that the problem occurs when Qt Designer loads the python custom widgets, I don't really remember where I got my libpyqt5.so (the C++ widget which tells designer how to read the python widgets), but I cannot find it on my recent PyQt5 installation, maybe that plugin points to the folder.

Any hint or help?

Comment: Did you read the [relevant pyqt docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#writing-qt-designer-plugins)?

Comment: Yes, but it says nothing about which lib folder is going to use, I guess by default it uses python3, maybe if I change the folder name I will see how the designer behaves

Comment: It says: "PyQt5 installs a C++ plugin in Designer’s plugin directory". Obviously this plugin must be compatible with whatever version of pyqt5 you are using.

Comment: Yes, it is compatible, I built PyQt5 from riverbank source, and didn't notice that it built the plugin, however I found a .pro-in file which seems to be the one for the plugin, maybe I can compile it, but even though

Comment: No, it is ***not*** compatible: that is why you are getting those errors. Clearly, it is linked against the wrong version of pyqt5.

Comment: Okay, I get your point, let me try to compile it with my recent PyQt5

Comment: I get it working using python 3.7, as I investigate, seems like python 3.5 can only use PyQt5 5.9.1 or lower, as above it uses a symbol that python doesn't have.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting this at the top of the file:

```
import os,sys
sys.path.insert(1,'/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages')
```

at the top of your python file; could be a work-around?